# define and use global jquery functions from 2 different files

Tags: 7, javascript

I am attempting to define a jQuery function in A.js in the following way:

```
jQuery.fn.demo = function(){
    console.log("heizsa!");
}
```

I am trying to run this function from B.js file this way:

```
jQuery().demo();
```

Having no luck there. Both .js are defined within the same module. 
Any idea how this is doable?

Files are included in the .info file this way:

```
scripts[] = js/A.js
scripts[] = js/B.js
```

Comment: How are you adding the script files? If it's in your .info file which order are you including them in? And same question if you're using `drupal_add_js()`

Comment: Hey @Clive yes through the .info file. I will also update the description because that's a quite important element

Comment: Try jQuery.demo() instead of jQuery().demo()

Comment: No worries, easy mistake, even Clive missed it ;-)